# Vector cross product in non-orthogonal basis system

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm given a non-orthogonal basis system  $\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{t}$ and i need to express linearly the following vector  $\vec{u} \times \vec{v}$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors. So assuming $ \vec{u} \times \vec{v} = \alpha_1\vec{u} + \alpha_2\vec{v} + \alpha_3\vec{t}$ and using the properties of the cross product I get the system of equations:

$\begin{cases} \alpha_1\vec{u}^2 + \alpha_2\vec{u}\vec{v} + \alpha_3\vec{u}\vec{t} & = & 0 \\ \alpha_1\vec{u}\vec{v} + \alpha_2\vec{v}^2 + \alpha_3\vec{v}\vec{t}&  =& 0\\ (\alpha_1\vec{u} + \alpha_2\vec{v} + \alpha_3\vec{t})^2 & = & (\vec{u}\vec{v})^2\sin^2{(\vec{u}, \vec{v})} \end{cases}$

which seems really hard to solve. Is there any other way i can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin{\rfloor}}
$We can get the answer directly with a bit of [geometric algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra).

Assume $(u,v,t)$ is left-handed.

First find the absolute triple product
$$
  S := |(u\times v)\cdot t| = \sqrt{-(u\wedge v\wedge t)^2},
$$$$
  -(u\wedge v\wedge t)^2 = \begin{vmatrix}u^2&u\cdot v&u\cdot t\\v\cdot u&v^2&v\cdot t\\t\cdot u&t\cdot v&t^2\end{vmatrix} = u^2v^2t^2 + (u\cdot v)(v\cdot t)(t\cdot u) + (u\cdot t)(v\cdot u)(t\cdot v) - (u\cdot t)v^2(t\cdot u) - (u\cdot v)^2t^2 - u^2(v\cdot t)^2.
$$

Now we compute
$$
  Su\times v = u\wedge v\lcontr u\wedge v\wedge t = u\lcontr\Bigl[(v\cdot u)v\wedge t - v^2u\wedge t + (v\cdot t)u\wedge v\Bigr] = (v\cdot u)(u\cdot v)t - (v\cdot u)(u\cdot t)v - v^2u^2t + v^2(u\cdot t)u + (v\cdot t)u^2v - (v\cdot t)(u\cdot v)u.
$$
All together,
$$
  u\times v = \frac{\bigl[v^2(u\cdot t)-(v\cdot t)(u\cdot v)\bigr]u + \bigl[u^2(v\cdot t)-(v\cdot u)(u\cdot t)\bigr]v + (u\cdot v)^2t}{\sqrt{u^2v^2t^2 + (u\cdot v)(v\cdot t)(t\cdot u) + (u\cdot t)(v\cdot u)(t\cdot v) - (u\cdot t)v^2(t\cdot u) - (u\cdot v)^2t^2 - u^2(v\cdot t)^2}}.
$$
If $(u,v,t)$ is right-handed then this answer simply gets negated.

Comment: It should have occurred to me first, but this is also what you get by applying Cramer's rule to OP's system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is indeed really hard. In order to simplify let me suppose $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{t}$ are at least unit vectors, and that they form a right-handed basis. Let us note $$\alpha=(\vec{v},\vec{t});~~~\beta=(\vec{t},\vec{u});~~~\gamma=(\vec{u},\vec{v})$$ the angles between the vectors of the basis.

Then let $\vec{t'}$ be a unit vector of same direction and sense than $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$, and let $\vec{v'}$ be a unit vector in the same plane than $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ such that $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v'}$, $\vec{t'}$ is orthonormal. Note that as $\vec{t'}$ is colinear to $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$ it is orthogonal to the plane containing $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ so that $\vec{v'}=\vec{t'}\times\vec{u}$ exists. Finally let $\delta$ be the angle $(\vec{t},\vec{t'})$.

Now that notations are set let me express $\vec{t}$ in the basis $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v'}$, $\vec{t'}$. As it is orthonormal we can use the scalar product: $$\vec{t}\cdot\vec{u}=\cos\beta;~~~\vec{t}\cdot\vec{t'}=\cos\delta$$ Finding $\vec{t}\cdot\vec{v'}$ is a bit more difficult: we need to express $v'$. As it is in the same plane than $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, as it is orthogonal to $\vec{u}$, and as $\alpha=(\vec{u},\vec{v})$, we get $$v=\cos\gamma\vec{u}+\sin\gamma\vec{v'}$$ But $\sin\gamma\neq 0$ as $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are not colinear. Thus, $$\vec{v'}=\frac{1}{\sin\gamma}\vec{v}-\frac{\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}\vec{u}$$ giving $$\vec{t}\cdot\vec{v'}=-\frac{\cos\gamma\cos\beta}{\sin\gamma}+\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\gamma}$$ and $$\vec{t}=\cos\beta\vec{i}+\left(\frac{\cos\alpha-\cos\gamma\cos\beta}{\sin\gamma}\right)\vec{v'}+\cos\delta\vec{t'}~~~~(1)$$ This equality between vectors means equality of their squared norm:$$1=\cos^2\beta+\left(\frac{\cos\alpha-\cos\gamma\cos\beta}{\sin\gamma}\right)^2+\cos^2\delta$$ I will spare the details but it gives $$\cos\delta=\frac{\sqrt{1-2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma-\cos^2\alpha-\cos^2\beta-\cos^2\gamma}}{\sin\gamma}$$ Note that the choice of orientation of the two basis ensure that $\cos\delta\ge 0$ making sure we chose the right squared root.

By definition of $\vec{t'}$ we have $$\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=\sin\gamma\vec{t'}$$ Using $(1)$ and after some more involved calculus we get $$\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=\frac{(\cos\alpha\cos\gamma-\cos\beta)\vec{u}+(\cos\gamma\cos\beta-\cos\alpha)\vec{v}+\sin^2\gamma\vec{t}}{\sqrt{1-2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma-\cos^2\alpha-\cos^2\beta-\cos^2\gamma}}$$ Using symmetry arguments this easily gives $\vec{v}\times\vec{t}$ and $\vec{t}\times\vec{u}$. Note also that when the original basis is orthonormal, all cosines are equal to $0$ and the sine is equal to $1$: we find the usual $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=\vec{t}$.

Finally I will comment your question. Looking at the form of the solution it seems very unlikely that there is an easier solution furthermore if $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{t}$ are not unit vectors. Maybe some calculus can be avoided but it remains necessary at some point. This proof rests on finding $\cos\delta$. I have spent most of the day trying to find a more geometrical approach to express $\delta$ using $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ with no success... It still is another way from what you were doing though.